# Trying to find the recursive function for a sequence of numbers. (Python)

Tags: python

| n | F(n) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 19 |
| 4 | 37 |
| 5 | 70 |
| ... | ... |
| 10 | 2062 |

Trying to determine the recursive function for he above sequence of numbers. Its also given that an even and an odd n are computed differently. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: this is what I have so far:

```py
def F(N):
    if N <= 0:
        return 1
    elif N % 2 == 0:
        return F(N-1) + (N-1) * 6
    else:
        return F(N-1) + (N) * 3
```

Comment: please show us your effort!

Comment: Is this your homework? What have you found so far?

Comment: @Kendle it is a test question from a few years ago on a practice sheet

Comment: Can you state in words what how the return is to be calculated? All we have to go on is your code which I assume is not producing the results you seek.

Comment: @JonSG we have to take an n value and return the corresponding number in the table above

Comment: How is n=5 not 52 then?  Alternatively, at you attempting to deduce the actual formula ?

Comment: @Kendle n=5 is meant to be 70

Comment: the general setting is an eigenvalue problem (with the companion matrix). What is important is to fix the order of the differential equation, i.e. how many terms are needed to generate the next...then is linear algebra

Answer (score 2):

It could be this formula:

2<sup>n+1</sup> + <sub>⌊</sub>3n/2<sub>⌋</sub> − 1

Here is JavaScript snippet that outputs the first 11 results:

```js
function F(n) {
    return 2**(n+1) + ((3*n)>>1) - 1;
}

for (let n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {
    console.log(n, F(n));
}
```

Python:

```py
def F(n):
    return 2**(n+1) + ((3*n)//2) - 1

for n in range(11):
    print(n, F(n))
```

### Recurrence relationship

F<sub>0</sub> = 1
F<sub>n</sub> = 2F<sub>n−1</sub> − 3<sub>⌊</sub>(n+1)/2<sub>⌋</sub> + 5

```js
function F(n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    return 2*F(n-1) - 3*((n+1)>>1) + 5;
}

for (let n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {
    console.log(n, F(n));
}
```

Python:

```py
def F(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    return 2*F(n-1) - 3*((n+1)//2) + 5

for n in range(11):
    print(n, F(n))
```

Comment: Nice, but a little unsatisfying for a problem looking for a recursive relation.

Comment: Added a recurrence.

Comment: what would the python version of this look like

Comment: Added python to it.

Comment: @trincot what would this look like with out the >> thing

Comment: That is the binary shift operator. In Python you can use the integer division operator instead (`//`). Updated.

Comment: @trincot How did you come up with that formula? Were you able to get it from something like worlframs or where you able to deduce it yourself?

Comment: I just played with the figures themselves. It starts by seeing that values grow exponentially, and that 2062 seems close to 2^11, and from there it is just looking how far off such formula is from the expected outcomes and filling the gaps...